# Must the energy of a topological corner state in a 2D material vanish?

Tags: topological-order, topological-phase

It seems that all the literature (just to name a few: [Phys. Rev. Lett. 124, 166804](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.124.166804), [Phys. Rev. Research 2, 013330](https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.013330), [Phys. Rev. Lett. 123, 073601](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.073601), and [Phys. Rev. Lett. 123, 256402](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.256402)) says yes to the question in the title, but I find for the moment only one [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.10816.pdf) mentioning "nonzero energy corner states".

Anyone can provide a brief story on this? BTW, are there convenient ways to tell whether a corner state is topologically nontrivial or not?

Comment: The energy of a topological corner state does not need to be zero (in the absence of particle-hole symmetry). Perhaps it would be helpful to link to some examples of "all the literature" that are leading you to believe otherwise?

Comment: @DominicElse Thx for the response. OK, let me list some.